# Reading File in J2ME

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, emulation

I became so much upset with this simple code segment:

```
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///root1/photos/2.png");
System.out.println(is.available());
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[is.available()];
int sizef = is.read(fileBytes);
System.out.println("filesize:"+sizef);
```

When I deploy this midlet in my mobile (with proper file location) It works properly i.e it shows proper filesize, but in the pc emulator it is constantly giving filesize of: 0. Obviously no Exception and I have the proper file in that location.

I am using j2mewtk sdk in netbeans 6.9. I tried uninstalling, installing wtk & netbeans.

Another thing is Everytime I run the emulator it creates `C:\Users\Mahsruf\j2mewtk\2.5.2\appdb\temp.DefaultColorPhone6` new location like `temp.DefaultColorPhone1,2,3,4` etc.

If I use jme SDK 3.0 in netbeans the file size is still 0, but now with a extra line in output window: `[WARN] [rms     ] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for: C:\Users\Mahsruf\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_delete_notify.dat`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not coding related issue. If multiple instances of the same emulator skin run simultaneously, the toolkit generates unique file paths for each one. For example, on Windows instances of DefaultColorPhone might have a file path name of workdir\appdb\temp.DefaultColorPhone1, workdir\appdb\temp.DefaultColorPhone2, and so forth.

**Solution:** The file workdir\appdb\DefaultColorPhone\in.use keeps track of the number of storage roots marked as in use. If the emulator crashes, you need to delete the in.use file

Comment: Thanks it solved the multiple instance/folder problem. But still file size is 0 in the emulator! Isn't it a bit strange!